# How to add html tag in template String in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web

```
    const warning = <strong>t('Warning')</strong>
    const helperMessage = `${warning} ${t(
    'phrases:updating your name can impact your production environment.'
  )}`
```

I want the text Warning as bold and rest of the text as normal.
t() is a function for translation

Comment: Is `t` from a library such as `react-i18next` or your own implementation?

Comment: t from react-i18next ibrary